# How to get chrome extension to sendMessage only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

The current version of my chrome extension extracts a set of strings from the current tab, opens a new tabs with a specific url and proceeds to insert the strings and submit the form using jQuery. The problem that I have is if I open a separate tab afterwards and go to the URL with the form, it proceeds to insert the data again and submit the form. It will do this continuously, so I can never use the website outside of automating it with the chrome extension.

This is the function in the background.js that sends the strings.

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) { //Fired when User Clicks ICON
    if(zip){
        zipCode = zip;
        zip = null;
    }else{
        zipCode = prompt('Zip code');
    }    
    if(/^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$/.test(zipCode)){
        var newURL = "https://www.medicare.gov/find-a-plan/questions/home.aspx?search";
        chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL });
        chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
            id = "2136760320";          
            if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {   
                chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
                    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {zip: zipCode, pass: pwd, drugID: id}, function(response) {});  
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

This is the content Script that matches the URL and is inserted along with jquery. I would need this to only run if the chrome extension was the one that opened the page.

```
var pwd = "";
var id = "";

var onMessageHandler = function(message, sender, sendResponse){
    pwd = message.pass;
    id = message.drugID;
    $("#saveWorkID").val(id);
    var date = pwd.split("/");
    var month = date[0];
    if (month.length < 2) month = "0" + month;
    var day = date[1];
    var year = date[2];
    $("#month").val(month);
    $("#day").val(day);
    $("#year").val(year);
    $("#lnkFind span").trigger("click");
}
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(onMessageHandler);
```

There are two other content scripts running for the pages prior to the above page, but not sure if they are necessary.

This is the manigest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "PDP Lookup",
  "description": "Lookup the PDP druglist of a current user",
  "version": "1.0",
  "icons": {"48": "icon.png",
          "128": "icon128.png" },
  "browser_action":
  {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "background":{
    "scripts": [
      "jquery.js",
      "background.js"
    ]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "https://www.medicare.gov/find-a-plan/questions/home.aspx?search"
            ],
            "js": [
                "jquery.js",
                "stage1.js"
            ]
        },
        {
            "matches": [
                "https://www.medicare.gov/find-a-plan/questions/enter-your-information.aspx"
            ],
            "js": [
                "jquery.js",
                "stage2.js"
            ]
        },
        {
            "matches": [
                "https://XXX.XXX.XXX/XX*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "jquery.js",
                "search.js"
            ]
        },
        {
            "matches": [
                "https://plancompare.medicare.gov/pfdn/PlanFinder/DrugSearch"
            ],
            "js": [
                "jquery.js",
                "stage3.js"
            ]
        }

  ],
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "https://*/*",
    "http://*/*"
  ]
}
```

Any help on how to prevent the content script from trying to read the sent message would be appreciated.

Comment: This question seems to have your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20046803/remove-listener-when-given-url-is-visited-after-using-chrome-tabs-onupdated-addl

Answer (score 1):

Instead of injecting the content script through the manifest file, try injecting it  in the callback function of `chrome.tabs.create`, something like

`chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL }, function(tabcreated){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabcreated,{file:"jquery.js"},function(){
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabcreated,{file:"stage1.js"});
    });
 })`

This way it will be injected only after your extension creates the tab, and not when a tab with that URL is opened in any other way.